# Sqlalchemy filter data by time difference from time with timezone

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the section below to work and it keeps indicating not found.

```
    @router.get("/day", response_model=schemas.Post)
def get_post_day(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print(date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y"))
    now = datetime.now()
    twenty_four_hours_ago = now - timedelta(hours=24)
    print('twenty_four_hours_ago = ',twenty_four_hours_ago)
    post_raw = db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.created_at > twenty_four_hours_ago).filter(models.Post.created_at < now)
    print(post_raw)
    post = post_raw.all()
```

the result I get is the following:

> 14032022 twenty_four_hours_ago =  2022-03-13 21:41:44.602838 SELECT * FROM weather_data WHERE
> weather_data.created_at > %(created_at_1)s AND weather_data.created_at
> < %(created_at_2)s ←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:1560 - "←[1mGET
> /posts/day HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m

I am wondering if it has something to do with the way the time is formatted in the database.

```
created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable = False, server_default = text('now()'))
```

An example of the date output is below.

```
2022-03-14T23:43:57.064143+00:00
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you tag what database you are using?

Comment: Sorry, postgres

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact problem but try setting the timezone to UTC for `now`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```